# Speed-up Windows AMI startup times

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

It takes a long time to boot up AWS EC2 Windows images, even up to 15 minutes. What process is causing this to take so long? Any way to boot up Windows servers faster?

Answer (score 3):

Standard Amazon Machine Images (AMIs) for Microsoft Windows have been shutdown with **SysPrep**, which removes the security identifier (SID), the computer name, the event logs, and specific drivers.

See: [Create a Standard Amazon Machine Image Using Sysprep](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ami-create-standard.html)

The down-side is that new Windows instances take longer to start. This only impacts the initial boot. If the instances is Stopped and Started, it will be fast to boot.

You could create an AMI without SysPrep being activated. Just be aware that this could cause problems if there are multiple instances on the same network launched from the same AMI, since they would share the same identifier.